# Why do the widths of my textboxes differ when the code is effectively identical (iTextSharp)?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I've got a PDF file that I'm generating using iTextSharp; here's a part of it that is causing me to suffer from  called alopecia areata due to excessive head-scratching:

[image]

Here's the code:

The longer initial text box on the row (below "Tier 2 Signature..."):

```
PdfPTable tblSection6_Row6 = new PdfPTable(5);
tblSection6_Row6.WidthPercentage = 100;
float[] tableCellSection6_6_Widths = new float[] { 460f, 40f, 225f, 40f, 235f };
tblSection6_Row6.SetWidths(tableCellSection6_6_Widths);
tblSection6_Row6.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

PdfPCell cellTextBoxTier2SigRequired = new PdfPCell()
{
    CellEvent = new DynamicTextbox("textBoxTier2SignatureReqd"),
    Phrase = new Phrase(boxFundingApproverSignature.Text, timesRoman9Font)
};
tblSection6_Row6.AddCell(cellTextBoxTier2SigRequired);

Phrase blankPhraseSec6Row6_1 = new Phrase();
PdfPCell blankCellSec6Row6_1 = new PdfPCell(blankPhraseSec6Row6_1);
blankCellSec6Row6_1.BorderWidth = 0;
tblSection6_Row6.AddCell(blankCellSec6Row6_1);

PdfPCell cellTextBoxPrintNameRow6 = new PdfPCell()
{
    CellEvent = new DynamicTextbox("textBoxPrintNameRow6"),
    Phrase = new Phrase(boxFundingApproverPrinted.Text, timesRoman9Font)
};
tblSection6_Row6.AddCell(cellTextBoxPrintNameRow6);

Phrase blankPhraseSec6Row6_2 = new Phrase();
PdfPCell blankCellSec6Row6_2 = new PdfPCell(blankPhraseSec6Row6_2);
blankCellSec6Row6_2.BorderWidth = 0;
tblSection6_Row6.AddCell(blankCellSec6Row6_2);

PdfPCell cellTextBoxDateRow6 = new PdfPCell()
{
    CellEvent = new DynamicTextbox("textBoxDateRow6"),
    Phrase = new Phrase(boxFundingApproverDate.Text, timesRoman9Font)
};
tblSection6_Row6.AddCell(cellTextBoxDateRow6);

doc.Add(tblSection6_Row6);
```

The shorter initial text box on the row (below "Senior Officer Signature..."):

```
PdfPTable tblSection6_Row8 = new PdfPTable(5);
tblSection6_Row6.WidthPercentage = 100;
float[] tableCellSection6_8_Widths = new float[] { 460f, 40f, 225f, 40f, 235f };
tblSection6_Row8.SetWidths(tableCellSection6_8_Widths);
tblSection6_Row8.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;

PdfPCell cellTextBoxSeniorOfficer = new PdfPCell()
{
    CellEvent = new DynamicTextbox("textBoxSeniorOfficer"),
    Phrase = new Phrase(boxSeniorOfficerSignature.Text, timesRoman9Font)
};
tblSection6_Row8.AddCell(cellTextBoxSeniorOfficer);

Phrase blankPhraseSec6Row8_1 = new Phrase();
PdfPCell blankCellSec6Row8_1 = new PdfPCell(blankPhraseSec6Row8_1);
blankCellSec6Row8_1.BorderWidth = 0;
tblSection6_Row8.AddCell(blankCellSec6Row8_1);

PdfPCell cellTextBoxPrintNameRow8 = new PdfPCell()
{
    CellEvent = new DynamicTextbox("textBoxPrintNameRow8"),
    Phrase = new Phrase(boxSeniorOfficerPrinted.Text, timesRoman9Font)
};
tblSection6_Row8.AddCell(cellTextBoxPrintNameRow8);

Phrase blankPhraseSec6Row8_2 = new Phrase();
PdfPCell blankCellSec6Row8_2 = new PdfPCell(blankPhraseSec6Row8_2);
blankCellSec6Row8_2.BorderWidth = 0;
tblSection6_Row8.AddCell(blankCellSec6Row8_2);

PdfPCell cellTextBoxDateRow8 = new PdfPCell()
{
    CellEvent = new DynamicTextbox("textBoxDateRow8"),
    Phrase = new Phrase(boxSeniorOfficerDate.Text, timesRoman9Font)
};
tblSection6_Row8.AddCell(cellTextBoxDateRow8);

doc.Add(tblSection6_Row8);
```

Or, here they are in KDiff, showing the only diffs are where "6" (for Row 6) is "8" on Row 8:

[image]

What could be causing this inconsistent behavior (mismatch in textbox width)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to try using more distinctive variable names or moving these large chunks of code into dedicated methods.

Your problem is the second line of your first block of code where you're using `tblSection6_Row6` instead of `tblSection6_Row8`:

```
tblSection6_Row6.WidthPercentage = 100;
```

Should be:

```
tblSection6_Row8.WidthPercentage = 100;
```